# Docker desktop networking Windows and Linux nodes

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a windows service within a Docker container that needs to access a MySQL database in a Linux container on the same machine (dev machine currently).

I thought of creating an overlay network on the two "nodes" on the same machine but this isn't possible as creating the swarm worker fails on windows after creating the swarm master on linux.

Is this possible, if not what is the easiest way of doing this? The purpose of the windows container is simply to deploy to a test environment to gather data. Do I need to deploy the linux to the cloud or another machine maybe, so the windows container can communicate?

Comment: Do you have a docker-compose that we can see how are the things setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use docker compose, it will create the network automatically. Replace the MySQL host with the MySQL service name you defined in the compose yaml file. Detailed information please refer to [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/08_using_compose/).